# make compile-goto-error use view-mode when visiting source buffer

Tags: compile-mode, view-mode

After using `M-x find-grep` I have a list of files with position information in a *compile* buffer. Now I want to **visit** the files to check, which can be done with `<RET>`, calling `compile-goto-error` to switch/open file into buffer at given position. Emphasize on visit, I want to quickly leave the visited buffer by typing `q`.

I looked into the source of `compile-goto-error` and added the view-mode line with `progn` around the `(setq compilation-current-error (point))` clueless as I am like this:

```
(defun my-compile-goto-error (&optional event)
  "Visit the source for the error message at point.
Use this command in a compilation log buffer."
  (interactive (list last-input-event))
  (if event (posn-set-point (event-end event)))
  (or (compilation-buffer-p (current-buffer))
      (error "Not in a compilation buffer"))
  (compilation--ensure-parse (point))
  (if (get-text-property (point) 'compilation-directory)
      (dired-other-window
       (car (get-text-property (point) 'compilation-directory)))
    (progn
      (setq compilation-current-error (point))
      (unless view-mode (view-mode t)))
    (next-error-internal)))
```

However, this works only every second time, with or without the line `(unless view-mode (view-mode t))`

How can I force `compile-goto-error` to open source-file in `view-mode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run `view-mode` before `next-error-internal`, which is the function that parses the error list, finds the next one, extracts the location information and visits the file. You need to run `view-mode` after `next-error-internal`, at the very end of the function.

Additionally, you need to ensure that `view-mode` runs in the correct buffer. This works out of the box in Emacs 27, but not in Emacs 26, where `next-error-internal` keeps the compilation output buffer as current. The source code buffer is displayed after `compile-goto-error` because `compilation-goto-locus` displays it in a window and selects this window, but that only causes the *buffer* to become current after the interactive function returns. So either run `view-mode` from a `next-error-hook` (but that would make it harder to not run `view-mode` all the time) or run it with the displayed buffer as current.

Since you don't need to change the way `compile-goto-error` works at all, just call it. The only thing you need to copy from the code of `compile-goto-error` is the argument specifications. (You could use the advice mechanism to avoid copying them but for what you're doing here that would be far more complicated.)

```
(defun compile-view-error (&optional event)
  "Like `compile-goto-error', but visit the file in view mode."
  (interactive (list last-input-event))
  (compile-goto-error event)
  (with-current-buffer (window-buffer)
    (view-mode t)))
```

Comment: @Juha I originally tested this on Emacs 27.1, it works there. It doesn't work on Emacs 26.3, I haven't yet figured why.

Comment: Yeah, using Emacs 26.3. What happens is that the compile buffer is set to view mode, not the visited source buffer. I looked into `next-error-internal`, the `current-buffer` call still returns the compile-mode buffer, not the visited source buffer. But I am way out of my way.

Comment: @Juha See my edit